# Starting a custom UEFI application from Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-8.1, uefi, bootmgr

Is it possible to make a boot menu entry in Windows Boot Manager BCD to start a custom (signed) UEFI application like, say, GRUB or Intel's UEFI Shell? What are the relevant bcdedit commands? It is assumed that UEFI environment is present and all applications are available on the ESP.